# How to delete duplicate line within a bracket preferably using one-liner?

Tags: awk, sed, perl

My intention is to remove duplicate Param within each test. There is multiple tests that might have duplicate Param and I want to remove the 2nd Param duplicate within each test.
My file is as below:

```
Test 1
{
  Param1 = "1";
  Param2 = "A";
  Param1 = "-1";
}
Test 2
{
  Param1 = "-1";
  Param3 = "B";
}
```

Expected output:

```
Test 1
{
  Param1 = "1";
  Param2 = "A";
}
Test 2
{
  Param1 = "-1";
  Param3 = "B";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk`:

```
awk '$0=="{" {delete params} { if ($1 in params) next; params[$1]=1 }1' file
```

This will save `$1` in `params` array and skip if `$1` present in that array. With every `{`, the array is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^}/{delete seen} !seen[$1]++' file
Test 1
{
  Param1 = "1";
  Param2 = "A";
}
Test 2
{
  Param1 = "-1";
  Param3 = "B";
}
```